# How can I change the transparency of the JSON model in the Three.js scene?

Tags: json, three.js, transparency, opacity

This painting is my JSON model.

[painting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJNet.jpg)

I understand that I can change the transparency by modify "transparent":true, and "opacity": 0.5  in the JSON file.

However, I want to change the opacity of the model after the JSON model has been loaded in the Three.js scene.

I use the method but it did not work.....

> mesh.material.transparent = true;
>    mesh.material.opacity = 0.1;

Here is my code.

```
jsonLoader2.load("models/pic.json", addPicToScn);

function addPicToScn(geometry, material) {
    var mtl = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(material);
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, mtl);
    mesh.scale.set(1.3, 1.3, 1.3);
    mesh.material.transparent = true;
    mesh.material.opacity = 0.1;
    mesh.castShadow = true;
    mesh.receiveShadow = true;
    mesh.rotation.set(2.8*Math.PI/5, 0, -Math.PI/2);
    mesh.position.set(0, 6, 21.8);
    scene.add(mesh);
            }
```

I really want to know the answer of this question....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model generates multiple materials which is why you are using MeshFaceMaterial. When you want to set transparency you need to set that on the materials from the model, not on the MeshFaceMaterial.

so code should be as follows:

```
jsonLoader2.load("models/pic.json", addPicToScn);

function addPicToScn(geometry, material) {
    var mtl = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(material);
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, mtl);
    mesh.scale.set(1.3, 1.3, 1.3);
    mesh.material.materials.forEach(function(m){
        m.transparent = true;
        m.opacity = 0.1;
    };
    mesh.castShadow = true;
    mesh.receiveShadow = true;
    mesh.rotation.set(2.8*Math.PI/5, 0, -Math.PI/2);
    mesh.position.set(0, 6, 21.8);
    scene.add(mesh);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

try `mesh.material.needsUpdate = true`

and take a look at : https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Updates

Comment: Thank you for your response!